# Unable to write a txt file to phone memory on android

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream, android-file

I tried to write a txt file to the phone's memory.

I use this code :

```
FileOutputStream out3 = null;
try { 
    out3 = new FileOutputStream(
        Environment.getRootDirectory() + "/a_directory/b.txt");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I get an error. It says `out3` is `null`. Why?

When I use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` it is working, but I want to write to the phone memory?

Comment: Seems You might need rooted device to write to root directory. Have You tried http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29 ?

Comment: I tried to make your question understandable. Please try to do this on your own next time...

Comment: Please use a more describing title. It would also be nice with a little more info on what you're trying to achieve in your question.

Comment: You should post your stacktrace as well.

Comment: it s not found ok? @DiegoPlentz it not found.

Comment: +1 to Baz for excellent edits!  This is a valid and relevant question; I'm sure the down-votes were because the original was so difficult to understand.

Comment: @sandrstar I just want to write phone directory because everyphone does not have sd card

Comment: @ErsinGulbahar I asked for the stacktrace because the only way I can imagine that out3 is null is a line later in the code, when you actually tries to use the variable. The code you posted never try to use the variable, so, there's no place it can say it's null.

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar Note that, due to historical design and evolution, the "external storage" is, in fact, internal on-board flash storage instead of an actual physical removable sd card.

Comment: In addition to the issue with writing to an invalid location covered at the duplicate link, you may have an additional problem of needing to create your intermediate directory "a_directory" before you can create a file within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the follwong code:

```
        File myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), "file.txt");


                     try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);
          OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
          osw.append(text.getEditableText().toString());
          osw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I dont want to write external memory ?

Comment: Then don't accept an answer that is about writing to external memory...

Answer (score -1):

You can't write to the internal memory without root, Android OS is wrote this way to protect the OS.  Instead there is a formatted amount of space that acts like an sd card on the main memory used for ringtones and other personalized data.  All droids are formatted to have or use an sd card, even the galaxy nexus has an internal SD card.  Writing the file to the card will hit a larger array of the devices.  Otherwise you will require root access and only 10% of android devices are rooted.

Comment: if a phone doest have sdcard what ca i do? I must write a txt file to the phone . where can I write ?

Comment: simple answer is you can't. to save something, instead of writing a text  file so that you can read it later, you could use a database (http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: The phones have minimal data without the cards, minus the nexus series and tablets which are built with internal memory still save to the "sd card" folder.  You should write the check for the card then write to the card.  Otherwise you need root access

Comment: This answer is completely mistaken.  Every android application has always had it's own storage area in the internal memory of the device.  See the developers docs on "saving files"